# npgsql:How to know issure row number from postgreexception using beginbinaryimport

Tags: .net, npgsql

we are using NpgsqlBinaryImporter for bulk insertions. 
our design is to remove the record which causes postgre exception error codes of 23 series or similar error codes and insert in the seperate table
retry with the remaining records

From the postgresexception, we are able to fetch the issue row/record from detail property or in the data dictionary.

Is there a way to know the row number out of total rows so that we can remove in a generic way from the collection as currently, we need to parse the detail property and see it matches with the insertion collection.

For example:
Error code:23502
Failing row contains (null, 299.56, 2017-07-18 17:03:19.395513, 2017-07-18 17:08:02.671517, 99.99, 99, \xffffffff, 
This is easy as we know that it is the first field is null which is not suppose to be, in the case of constraints which are combined with two columns it would be more difficult.
Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're importing many rows via COPY and if an exception occurs you'd like to know which row number you're on? If so, I don't think there's any mechanism that would provide it - PostgreSQL does not provide this information on the exception AFAIK.

Comment: thanks for understanding the question and reply to same. will change my design to take the failed batch and run a separate thread to insert one by one record and move the issue record to other table.